# Permissions on non Drupal generated content

Tags: hooks

Relative newcomer to Drupal 7 and I'm still coming to terms with some of the naming conventions used, so please forgive me if I bork the language up front.

The problem I am trying to solve:

I'm going to build a community / logged in user content website

I'm rebuilding from another existing site, but only manually copying content over (the current site is not built in Drupal).

I have HTML5 microsites in the current environment and I plan to copy them across to the new, but I want to ensure that there are user permissions applied to them so that only logged in users can view the pages.

How do I solve this problem? Is there a module that can "import" content? Or some code I can embed in the pages?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to convert your microsite to use Drupal's API (`hook_menu`, `hook_theme`, etc) if you want to use the permission system. It's hard to imagine that there's a module that would be able to do that, there are too many variables involved. It's very likely to be a manual process, unlikely that there are shortcuts

Comment: Also, questions asking for modules are off-topic for us.